# Compare the number of instructions executed on the SIMD machine to the MIMD machine

Tags: architecture, cpu-architecture

We would like to execute the loop below as efficiently as possible. We have two different machines, a MIMD machine and a SIMD machine.

```
for (i=0; i<2000; i++)
    for (j=0; j<3000; j++)
        X_array[i][j] = Y_array[j][i] + 200;
```

Q1. For a 4 CPU MIMD machine, what is the speed-up for this MIMD machine?

Q2. For an eight-wide SIMD machine (i.e., eight parallel SIMD functional units), compare the number of instructions executed on the SIMD machine to the MIMD machine.

I think Q1's answer is 4 but I don't know Q2..
How to solve this problem?

Comment: This looks like homework, and on SO homework questions are expected to show some effort towards a solution.. It cannot be expected that SO users will just give a solution. Please edit to show what has been tried.

Comment: Multi-core vs. SIMD aren't conflicting choices, they're orthogonal.  In fact most real-world multi-core CPUs have some form of SIMD, because SIMD instructions are worth adding to a single core before it's worth creating the complexity of a multi-core CPU.  The speedup for using multiple threads is usually only significant for large problems, because threads have a lot of startup overhead on most systems.  Your factor of 4 perfect speedup is also assuming the threads don't compete for memory bandwidth or anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is nowhere near enough information to answer this without making a lot more assumptions that you haven't specified.

---

It's non-trivial to vectorize this problem with SIMD because the array indexing is reversed for `X[i][j]` vs. `Y[j][i]`.  **So the problem is to make a transposed copy of the array (and add `+200`)**  Yes SIMD can help, but you're going to need shuffle and blend instructions as well as vertical add, so the details depend a lot on the details of the shuffle and blend instructions the ISA provides.  Or strided loads or gather instructions?

And also on how smart your compiler is, whether it uses SIMD instructions at all.  Or whether it maybe loads a vector and does the `+200` with SIMD but then scatters the result with scalar?  Even the cost of extracting elements of a vector to memory depends on the ISA.  With x86 for example, SSE2 required a separate shuffle to get the element you want to the bottom of a vector.  But SSE4.1 added `pextrq` that could store a qword `double` to memory.  But the AVX version of it can only access the low 2 elements of a vector.

---

**Multi-core vs. SIMD aren't conflicting choices, they're orthogonal**.  In fact most real-world multi-core CPUs have some form of SIMD, because SIMD instructions are worth adding to a single core before it's worth creating the complexity of a multi-core CPU.

Running scalar code on 4 CPUs is normally a waste for problems with data parallelism.  In real life, you'd vectorize the problem with SIMD and then (if it's a big enough problem) split it up into multiple threads for MIMD x SIMD multiplicative speedup.

---

**The speedup for using multiple threads to access the same data might not be linear.**  This problem only touches each array element once, so it's probably memory bound.  But it has a difficult access pattern.  There's no basis for assuming that this problem will be ALU bound and scale linearly with the number of cores.  In practice cores will all be competing to read/write to the same RAM.  Or their private caches all need to read results.

With careful design of the transpose, you can probably avoid having multiple threads need to read the same cache lines very much.

Startup overhead is also significant for using MIMD thread-level parallelism in practice.  Maybe you're supposed to assume zero overhead, or that you're doing this repeatedly for different arrays with minimal synchronization cost?  Then sure you can assume zero startup overhead.

(Unless you're talking about instruction-level parallelism within a single core.  That's free.  But you mention a "4 CPU" system, implying thread-level parallelism as well.  Of course again in real life it's usually only worth building multiple cores after exploiting the low-hanging fruit for a single core with superscalar and SIMD, so real code is potentially running 3 vector instructions per clock on each core, with each instruction operating on 8 SIMD vector elements.)

e.g. that's what you'd get on a quad-core Skylake CPU with single-precision `float` vectors.

---

**But the question asks you work out *instruction* counts?**

> compare the number of instructions executed on the SIMD machine to the MIMD machine.

How do you know how much loop overhead there is, or how much the compiler unrolls.

And more importantly, how exactly the shuffle/blend instructions are designed to let you transpose.

**I wonder if the switched indexing was a mistake**, because it's a vastly simpler problem that's easily amenable to plain vertical SIMD if it's just a copy-and-add without the transpose.